# Convert line with words enclosed by single quotes and separated by comma to a column

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, tr

I have this file:
`'dog', 'cat', 'horse', 'turtle'`

I want to convert the line to:

```
dog
cat
horse
turtle
```

if I use just the comma as separator and command tr I can do:
`tr -s ','  '\n' < file`

with the output

```
'dog'
 'cat'
 'horse'
 'turtle'
```

But when I use `', '` as separator, this doesn't work:

`tr -s '\', \''  '\n' < file`

even if I use double back slash to escape the single quotes it still does not work.
The only output I get in the terminal is `>`.

How do I correctly escape the single quotes to get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed` command:

```bsh
$ sed -e "s/', '/\n/g" -e "s/'//g" file 
dog
cat
horse
turtle
```

Answer (score 5):

Treating the input as quoted CSV, with skippable whitespace after each comma delimiter and using single quotes rather than the standard double quotes as quoting characters, we may use `csvformat` to reformat the data:

```bsh
$ csvformat -S -q "'" -D $'\n' file
dog
cat
horse
turtle
```

This uses `csvformat` with `-S` to skip the initial whitespace characters after each delimiter, `-q "'"` to set the input quoting character to a single quote, and then `-D $'\n'` to set the output field delimiter to a newline character.

The file is then reformatted.

Any field using embedded newlines would be quoted in the output, as would field containing embedded double quotes be.

Answer (score 4):

`tr` works on sets, not on strings. Each first symbol in the first set is replaced with the first symbol from the second set, second symbol from the first set with a second symbol from a second set, etc.

If second set has less symbols than the first one - all the symbols from the first set which doesn't have a proper pair is replaced with the last symbol of the second set.

You need

```
tr -s "\', "  '\n' < file
```

Each apostrophe, comma, and space is replaced with line feed, but the -s option squeeze all of them into one instance of LF.

Comment: This leaves a blank line at the beginning.

Comment: Yes, it does. Because EACH letter from the first set is replaced with LF, and the source file has apostrophe at the beginning.

The solution could be to use ```tr``` twice - remove apostrophes and then change commas to LF. Or go by way of ```sed```.

Comment: Your `"\', "` string includes a (literal) backslash, so your command would treat backslashes in the input as word separators.  That wouldn’t be a problem for the sample input shown in this question, but it might cause trouble in some other scenario. You should use just `"', "` — you don’t have to escape `'` when you use it in `"..."`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F"'" '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i}' file
dog
cat
horse
turtle
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `grep` or  compatible when built with pcre support:

```
grep -Po "[\s,']*\K[^']*" < file
```

Note that it skips empty quoted strings (as in `'empty', 'like', ''`).

`[\s,']` skips all whitespace, commas and single quotes, and then we `K`eep what follows: the next sequence of non-`'` characters.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed "s/\([^,]*\), /\1\n/g;s/'//g" input_file
dog
cat
horse
turtle
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '!(NR%2)' RS=\' file
dog
cat
horse
turtle
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/^.|.$/,"");gsub(/., *./,"\n")} 1' file
dog
cat
horse
turtle
```

Also see this: http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote
If we base on its reference, we can do:

```
awk '{gsub("\047","");gsub(/, */,"\n")} 1' file
dog
cat
horse
turtle
```

- or:

```
awk -v q="'" '{gsub(q,"");gsub(/, */,"\n")} 1' file
dog
cat
horse
turtle
```

Answer (score 0):

```
python -c "for s in eval(input()): print(s)" < file
dog
cat
horse
turtle
```